# Strategy for backing up a very large website (~40GB)

Tags: backup, tar

I have a website which works with lots and lots of text files - now they take up about 40 GB of data and increasing over time. I need to make a full daily backup. My current strategy is to make a password protected archive and store it in the dropbox with this command:

```
tar cfz - /var/www/mysite | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -k "b@ckupPassword" > /home/user/Dropbox/server_backups/sources/2013_01_04_0500_mysite_source_encrypted.tgz
```

It works, but making an archive takes about 14 hours and consumes a lot of IO - and it will be worse as the amount of data increases.

What is the proper strategy of backing up such large amount of files?

Comment: With that amount of data you should be using a database, not text files. It's a simple enough change and the benefits are great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `rsync`, provided I have space enough.

This example has a full backup and keeps a week of incremental ones.

```
#!/bin/bash

DAY=$(date +%A)

if [ -e /bkp/incr/$DAY ] ; then
  rm -fr /bkp/incr/$DAY
fi

ionice -c 3 rsync -a --delete --inplace --backup --backup-dir=/bkp/incr/$DAY /var/www/mysite/ /bkp/full/ &> /dev/null
```

The script can be complicated to store offsite, on dropbox folders and so on.

If you really need to use `tar`, you can keep track of the modified files

```
tar zcvf - --listed-incremental=/var/log/mysite.tarlog /var/www/mysite | openssl enc  ...
```

If you want a full backup, delete `/var/log/mysite.tarlog`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above rsync seems to be the best way to backup the whole site.
Yet i would suggest you to implement some sort of replicated filesystem, something like a simple GlusterFS volume with replication.

Replication is not a backup, but it can help you to reduce the I/O impact of backups and eventually provide you with a solid base to expand your website later into a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use an incremental backup mechanism in this case.

Using `rsync` you can take incremental backup.

Click on [me](http://www.techtrunch.com/linux/commands/rsync-fast-versatile-remote-local-filecopying-tool) for more details about using `rsync`

*Click on [me](http://www.backup4all.com/kb/incremental-backup-118.html) to read more about incremental backup*